# Nested 'Shells' with Durandal SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, durandal

With Durandal, I can have a shell where multiple views could be displayed and viewed.

I have a scenario where I have a a left-menu of links, clicking on a link should load a new view into the right side area. The left and right areas are both inside a single view.

Is the above doable with Durandal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple shells to accomplish this.  Simply create an html page, compose it from your shell.html, and then simply bind it to data as you normally would in the shell.  If you want to create a custom view model for the nav only you can do that as well although it is not required.  If you do this than just expose that viewmodel from your shell.js and call it as you normally would ex. navmenu.menuOptions

Comment: maybe I didn't mention that those right and left divs are part of a single view that itself will get replaced by another view that might have another structure. In other words, I have major and minor routes. Major routes to navigate main views, while minor routes to navigate through the views and place them inside the right-div.

Comment: Can you share what you got so far and explain ones more what you're trying to accomplish? You might want to review the [knockout samples](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/knockout-samples), [view compositin](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition) and [master detail](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/master-detail) to see various examples. You might need a combination of those to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 to Rainer's answer.  In your comment you say they are part of a single view, but remember - with KO view composition they don't have to be.  You can use <!-- ko compose: --><!--/ko--> to show views or views with view models.  I use a 'template' nav menu in an application that I am working on that knows nothing about what it is going to display, only that it displays something in a general format.  The shell view model decides what it shows, and it sounds like you are trying to accomplish the same thign.